# Leveraging field_get_items variable in a custom field template

Tags: 7, entities, theming

I can use a template preprocess function for node to simply get the alt tag of an image field image using the venerable `field_get_items` as such:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_node(&$vars, $hook) {
// Global node.
  $node = $vars['node'];

 $field_image_items = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_image');
  // Load individual data from 'field_image'.
    $vars['alt_caption'] = $field_image_items[0]['alt'];
}
```

Then in `node.tpl.php`, I can render the alt tag of the image from the variable we created above as:

```
<?php print $alt_caption; ?>
```

... and that works great.

However, I'd like to customize the template for the image itself so when I create a `field--field_image.tpl.php` template, sure enough the image renders fine but if I add the `$alt_caption` variable, that does not render. I'm guessing this will simply not work or there is an extra step I need to do for the variable to render in this new template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [TEMPLATE_preprocess_field()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/template_preprocess_field/7) function at `template.php`

You can use this preprocess function in same way as you are doing for `NODE`. Like -

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_field(&$vars) {
  if ($node = menu_get_object()){
    $node = $vars['node'];
    $field_image_items = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_image');
    $vars['alt_caption'] = $field_image_items[0]['alt'];
  }
}
```

Then go to your TPL made for your particular field and print it where ever you like just like you have mentioned --

```
<?php print $alt_caption; ?>
```

And it will work like charm!! I have implemented like this several times.

But yeah...don't forget to clear your cache after this implementation.

Comment: I'm getting a nasty error with that even after clearing cache: `Notice: Undefined index: node in gratis_preprocess_field() (line 266 of template.php).
EntityMalformedException: Missing bundle property on entity of type node. in entity_extract_ids() (line 7663 of /includes/common.inc).` -- It seems preprocess field does not like the node variable defined? (Note gratis is the name of my theme).

Comment: @DannyEnglander - Edited my answer after seeing my own template.php, please check now after updating your code :)
Otherwise there are other option to get relevant info of field by the machine name of field as it's available in $vars at TEMPLATE_preprocess_field()

Comment: Ok this now works but without `$node = $vars['node'];`, that still throws the error but if I take it out, it works well on a node page but not on my main page with teasers. There, I'm getting this error: `Notice: Undefined variable: alt_caption in include() (line 54 of field--field_image.tpl.php).` So not sure if this will end up being a good solution unless there is a way to make the variable available in the teaser?

Comment: @DannyEnglander - Because it expect menu_get_object() to get executed which take place on full node load.
Can you please output $vars inside this preprocess function by doing dsm($vars) & give me the result ?

Comment: @DannyEnglander - You can chat with me on IRC, I am in room #drupal & #drupal-support with name RajeevK

Comment: Hey thanks, I added the vars to a fiddle, too long for here: http://jsfiddle.net/highrockmedia/nMv7Z/1/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9389/discussion-between-rajeevk-and-danny-englander)

Answer (score 0):

As I was having issues with this working in teaser mode, another way to do this is to forgo the preprocess function altogether and render this in your custom image field template using the #item var that's already available:

```
 <?php if ($item['#item']['alt']): ?>
    <figcaption><?php print $item['#item']['alt']; ?></figcaption>
 <?php endif; ?>
```

This will render a nice HTML5 caption under the image based on your alt tag. What's interesting about this is that the default `field.tpl.php` template in D7 does not give `item` as a possible variable. [Inspiration for this method here](http://adaptivethemes.com/using-html5-figure-figcaption-elements-to-markup-image-fields-in-drupal-7).